# Jetty server hangs with large object pool without any requests being made

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jetty, pool

I am running a web application using jetty server with maven. The application contains a large pool of static objects in *Lists* and *Maps* contributing to the 2.8GB of physical memory usage. After several hours, the server hangs with maximum CPU usage. This happens without any user interaction or requests made on the server.

I have noticed that during those several hours, while the server is running fine, the memory slowly reduces to 1.7GB. My suspicion is that this could be a garbage collection related issue.

**Questions:**

1. Could it be that GC hangs while erroneously collecting or inspecting my large object pools and its references?
2. How would I go about debugging and fixing this issue?

Note that on Windows I do not have this problem. Once the application starts and fills up its pool, it occupies 3.4GB and stays exactly the same without ever crashing.

**Server startup and environment:**

```
setenforce 0
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx5120m -Xms5120m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xgcthreads1 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=2000 -XX:GCTimeRatio=10"
sudo nohup mvn -D jetty.port=80 jetty:run &
```

**Operating system:**

```
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
```

**Java:**

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

**Maven:**

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
```

**Jetty:**

```
8.1.8.v20121106
```

Comment: is this showing up during development with the jetty:run or are you trying to run a production type instance using both maven and jetty:run? if it is the later it is by no means a recommended deployment solution.

Comment: It is the later, i.e. a production type instance. It is a very lightweight service, hence the decision to go with Jetty. Although it's first time I use Jetty in production, I found that many companies use jetty in production. Are you suggesting that I should move to something more heavyweight such as Glassfish, JBoss, TomEE+ or that I should run the instance as a jar? Thx

Comment: no, just don't run it via the jetty-maven-plugin, either write a little embedded jetty wrapper or deploy it into a normal jetty distribution...is it not jetty that is the issue, it is a production deployment scenario using maven tooling which neither maven nor its jetty plugin were intended to be used for :)

Comment: Thank you for your input. After running Jetty under different configurations, I eliminated Jetty as a possible cause. However, I took your advice and I am running the app now using the jetty-runner `sudo nohup java -server -Xmx5120m -Xms5120m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=2000 -XX:GCTimeRatio=10 -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port 80 --path / target/geocoder.war & `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say if it's due to incorrect GC that cause the system hang. I think you can make some moves to get more information:

1. Add `-verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/admin/logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps` to your **JVM arguments**, those will help you find more information of GC.
2. Collecting **thread dump** regularly to see what's going on in your application at runtime.
3. Get a **memory dump** when the machine is about to die, which can be analyzed by MAT.
4. When CPU spikes, use `top -H -p<pid>` to **find the dominator threads** and spot them in the thread dump, then you can basically find out which line of the code is doing wrong.

Here is a really good article of [How to Analyze Java Thread Dumps](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-analyze-java-thread-dumps/).

Comment: Following up on your suggestions and the article (especially the `jstack` command) allowed me to debug and trace a possible cause for my problem. I am waiting to verify the solution, but it seems that neither GC nor Jetty were causing the hang, but rather a deadlock in using the DBCP's PoolingDataSource, i.e. programming error on my part.